# jQuery UI sortable breaks in IE8 table rows shrinks once row is dropped

Tags: jquery, user-interface, jquery-ui-sortable

iam facing an issue in JQuery UI sortable 1.8.3. It works fine in chrome. But when tested in IE8 once i drag the table row and drop it then all the rows shrink in size. I did some hack to ensure the table header widths are equal but despite doing that the table rows shrink once row is dropped.

can any one please help as iam facing this issue for quite long time.